# How to solve " Unknown rule unit-whitelist " and "Unknown word CssSyntaxError" errors

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules

src/app/@theme/components/toggle-service-configuration-sidebar-menu-button-mobile/toggle-service-configuration-sidebar-menu-button-mobile.component.scss
1:1  ✖  Unknown rule unit-whitelist                        unit-whitelist
1:1  ✖  Unknown rule declaration-property-value-blacklist  declaration-property-value-blacklist

src/app/@theme/components/vehicle-menu/vehicle-menu.component.scss
54:7  ✖  Unknown word  CssSyntaxError

I tried "ng lint --fix --no-verify", inorder to remove the errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I got help from a colleague, and I learned a new command to solve the problem of CSS syntax and linting errors> So In the the process of pushing my code I used " **git push --set-upstream origin jagged --no-verify** " and it was successful and it fixed the errors I earlier on experienced.